# MySQL: update without changing data, possible?

Tags: mysql, triggers

Is it possible in MySQL to update a row, without changing any data?

I just need a trigger to do its work, but the data should not be changed.

Of course I could do an update and then another update, but the trigger is quite slow (deletes and inserts 500 rows everytime) and I have to update thousands of rows, so I'd rather not do it twice.

I could also just update a dummy field with NOW(),  but I'm just curious if it's possible without 'tricks'.

Comment: I think you have other problems than using 'tricks' when a single trigger inserts 500 rows to be honest.

Comment: well, the update runs quite fast, takes about 0.2 secs... it's a table that doesn't get updated very often...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about:

```
UPDATE table SET id=id WHERE ...
```

Comment: But.. if the value is the same as current - it doesn't call "ON UPDATE".
And "affected rows"  = 0 after such query. 
I just tried in phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 3):

You should just be able to run an `UPDATE` command with the same data that already exists in the row. No data will change, but the trigger will still fire.