# UPDATE Statement without changing value

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently, I am working on `node` with `express` library using `mysql` connector. So most likely I am working with string literal `SQL Query`.

Now, I have implemented a design wherein I do have a constant formula on query.

Table Structure:

```
╔═══╦═════════════════════╦═══════════════╗
║   ║ Field Name          ║ Type          ║
╠═══╬═════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 1 ║ groupLevel          ║ varchar       ║
║ 2 ║ insideBranchAccess  ║ boolean       ║
║ 3 ║ outsideBranchAccess ║ boolean       ║
║ 4 ║ ipadFunctionID      ║ varchar       ║
║ 5 ║ createdBy           ║ varchar       ║
║ 6 ║ approvedBy          ║ varchar       ║
╚═══╩═════════════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

SQL Query:

```
INSERT INTO iPadFunctionAccess 
(groupLevel, insideBranchAccess, outsideBranchAccess, ipadFunctionID, createdBy, approvedBy) 
VALUES 
?
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
insideBranchAccess = VALUES(insideBranchAccess), 
outsideBranchAccess = VALUES(outsideBranchAccess), 
updatedBy = VALUES(createdBy);
```

So the `?` is where I insert my data. The sample data that I insert is this

```
(5, false, true, 'IIU.A05', 'SYSTEM', 'SYSTEM')
```

Actual Database:
[image: insert event]

The sample data that I am getting from the application is this.

```
[
    {
        "id": "DEP.A03",
        "groupLevel": "5",
        "insideBranchAccess": true,
        "outsideBranchAccess": true
    },
    {
        "id": "DEP.S02",
        "groupLevel": "5",
        "insideBranchAccess": true
    },
    {
        "id": "DEP.S04",
        "groupLevel": "5",
        "outsideBranchAccess": true
    }
]
```

So as you can see, the `insideBranchAccess` and `outsideBranchAccess` is kinda optional.

I have seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7408573/2637261) so I have come up with this kind of query. So incase that I only got `insideBranchAccess` my query should be like this

```
(5, true, outsideBranchAccess, 'IIU.A05', 'SYSTEM', 'SYSTEM')
```

and vice versa.

Actual Database:
[image]

However, when I do this, the `outsideBranchAccess` always return to `false` even though the previous data from the database is `true`. Any thoughts?

MySQL Fiddle: [HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9a489c6efb84717c261a079f497448dd)

Comment: I think you missunderstood the answer in the other post. Not changing in that case meens there is the same data as before in the same row not as in the dataset of the row before. So for an insert this will not work.

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff I am trying to pull the same `data` from that row to reuse it on the `UPDATE`, the initial data from the row is `true`, so when I put `outsideBranchAccess `, it should pull the `true` and not the `false` as far as I assume what it should do.

Comment: In `INSERT` part you try to insert `outsideBranchAccess`? of course you insert NULL. Which is treated as FALSE in ODKU part. PS. It is strange that you do not receive error "Unknown field"...

Comment: @Akina The `INSERT` part would be out of the question since I do have a `UNIQUE INDEX` that will trigger the `UPDATE` event. By right, the first query that you will see will trigger `INSERT` assuming that the data is not existing, but on the second query, it will trigger the `UPDATE` since the data is already existing. So by right, the `outsideBranchAccess` has initial value of `true`, and on the update, since I reference it to `outsideBranchAccess` directly, it should get `true`, and note `false`

Comment: *The INSERT part would be out of the question* NO. You use `INSERT INTO iPadFunctionAccess 
(groupLevel, insideBranchAccess, outsideBranchAccess, ipadFunctionID, createdBy, approvedBy) 
VALUES (5, true, outsideBranchAccess, 'IIU.A05', 'SYSTEM', 'SYSTEM') ...` which MUST result in error.

Comment: @Akina what will be the error in case? I was able to insert it without any problem. That only thing I am encountering is this `UPDATE` issue. See my edit on the question

Comment: *what will be the error in case?* INSERT do not know what is `outsideBranchAccess` and it must produce "unknown field" or something similar. Exclusion - when INSERT is executed in SP where a variable named `outsideBranchAccess` exists (and its value is used in this case).

Comment: @Akina oh, now I understand what you are pointing out. However, the thing is I have inserted it without any problem, by right, the `UPDATE` problem is what I am trying to solve. And I think the problem in here is the referencing of the `column`. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Replace `outsideBranchAccess = VALUES(outsideBranchAccess)` with `outsideBranchAccess = COALESCE(VALUES(outsideBranchAccess), outsideBranchAccess)` (and the same for all another fields).

Comment: @Akina I have tried this solution and still get the same behaviour.

Comment: See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e10c40456c100551b74205635e8b114a - the value is NOT replaced with NULL during ODKU.

Comment: @Akina by right, we are doing the same thing, but it is weird I we both don't have the same result. please look at this [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9a489c6efb84717c261a079f497448dd). This is the exact structure of my table

Comment: Your `outsideBranchAccess` is defined as `NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'` - so you get `'0'`, not NULL, and COALESCE not acts. I do NOT see  how to distinguish in ODKU part does `'0'` value is set explicitly or is assigned implicitly to default value. So the task is not unsolvable in current state.

Comment: @Akina Oh I see, when I changed it to `NULLABLE` and remove the `default` it works fine. Can you create an answer for this so at least I can give the credits to you with your explanation. Thanks!

Comment: I'm too lazy... maybe you'll create self-answer?

Comment: @Akina but you won't get any reputation on that case? I just want to give the proper credits to you. You don't need to create it now, anytime you are willing and free to do so. Thanks man! Cheers.

Comment: Reputation? it is fake. Either solution works or not - and this is not reputation-dependent.